# MVC Basic Username and Password Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Looking for best way to implement basic authentication where user needs to enter username and password and I can control the database of users.

This is for c# and MCV application.

Just looking for a pointer or sample for best way to implement this in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using IIS, look at [HTTP Basic authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) configuration for that kind of requirment.

Using that authentication, the user automatically will be prompted to enter user & password.

Take on account that this mechanism is considered as very week protection and you should integrate SSL (HTTPS) with that.

**MSDN:**

> However, the disadvantage of Basic authentication is that it transmits
>   unencrypted base64-encoded passwords across the network. You should
>   use Basic authentication only when you know that the connection
>   between the client and the server is secure. The connection should be
>   established either over a dedicated line or by using Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) encryption and Transport Layer Security (TLS). For
>   example, to use Basic authentication with Web Distributed Authoring
>   and Versioning (WebDAV), you should configure SSL encryption.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty broad.
Use the basic Visual Studio authentication template:

[image]

Then, read about it more in [MSDN](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=299423).

Answer (score 0):

You could override the default membership and role providers if you wanted something simple. Take a look [here](http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx) for a nice tutorial on how to achieve this.